# Tapestry: Grid sorting/pagination links go to bad URL

Tags: java, tapestry

I am working on a page in Tapestry 5.1, temporarily named TestPage.tml/TestPage.java, the .tml containing a grid control (`<table t:type="grid" ... >`). When running the application, the grid displays all the data correctly, but I have a problem with pagination and column sorting. I'm running on `localhost:8080`, and what happens is whenever I click on the grid's pagination links, or any column sorting link, the browser tries to go to `testpage/` rather than the full URL, as evidenced by Chrome's address bar. Chrome then of course says the site could not be found.

To make matters stranger, I have another page that also has a grid and the sorting/pagination works fine. I'm not doing anything differently that I know of, with respect to the grid.

Other potentially pertinent info:

- No special sortModel has been set.
- The href for sort/pagination in the generated html source looks like, for example: `<a title="Go to page 23" href="testpage.grid.pager/23">23</a>` which should be treated as a relative URL, therefore taking me to `localhost:8080/testpage.grid.pager/23` when clicked.
- Changing some variable names to protect the innocent, my table tag looks like this:
  `<table t:type="grid" t:source="items" t:row="item" t:include="itemId,itemName,quantity" reorder="mark,itemId,itemName,quantity,summary" t:add="mark,features,summary" t:rowclass="prop:evenodd.next">` and again, the data displays just fine.
- By setting copious breakpoints in TestPage.java, I was able to see that the pageLoaded() method DOES get called when I click on either a pagination or sort link (but no other method I've defined is called). Therefore the back end of the page does seem to be accessed, for what it's worth. Perhaps Tapestry is returning me to the wrong page after hitting the back end for some reason.
- If I hover the mouse cursor over the link, the bottom browser bar displays the full URL.

I'd be happy to provide any other info if it could help lead to a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So I upgraded my Tapestry to 5.3 (from 5.1) and lo and behold, the bug is gone!